# Multiple checkboxes in list item android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I'm trying to build a custom array adapter that has two checkboxes in each list item. When a checkbox is clicked I want to uncheck the other checkbox if it's checked. So either neither checkbox is checked or just one of them is.

I think the issue I'm running into is I'm not clear how to reference the other checkbox from inside the onClickListener. Here's my code thus far:

```
public class PetWalkerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject>{
    protected Context mContext;
    protected List<ParseObject> mPets;

    public PetWalkerAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> pets) {
        super(context, R.layout.pet_walker_item, pets);
        mContext = context;
        mPets = pets;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView ==  null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.pet_walker_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.petPictureView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.petPicture);
            holder.petNameLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.petNameLabel);
            holder.ownerCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ownerCheckBox);
            holder.walkerCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.walkerCheckBox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            // If owner check is toggled, uncheck walker
            holder.ownerCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                    ViewHolder petHolder = (ViewHolder) cb.getTag();

                    // Here's where the app crashes, 
                    if (petHolder.walkerCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                        petHolder.walkerCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        ParseObject pet = mPets.get(position);

        holder.petNameLabel.setText(pet.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_PET_NAME));



        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView petPictureView;
        TextView petNameLabel;
        CheckBox ownerCheckBox;
        CheckBox walkerCheckBox;
    }

    public void refill(List<ParseObject> pets) {
        mPets.clear();
        mPets.addAll(pets);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Here's the logcat

```
10-02 01:53:16.412    1270-1270/com.base8.wlkr E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.base8.wlkr, PID: 1270
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.base8.wlkr.adapters.PetWalkerAdapter$1.onClick(PetWalkerAdapter.java:50)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please let me know if you need any more information. Any critiques or references are appreciated. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Please put the logcat for the crash.

Comment: Have you considered radio buttons?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I haven't thought about radio buttons, my goal is to loop through the list and see which option, if any, the user checked when they hit a **Save** button in another fragment. If I'm unable to get this working I may consider revising though, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set the tag for the rowview and then you are trying to retrieve for the CheckBox. You should do something like that: 
**Update**. Like I said I didn't check the code thoroughly, all you had to do is to make a small modification.

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView ==  null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.pet_walker_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.petPictureView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.petPicture);
        holder.petNameLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.petNameLabel);
        holder.ownerCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ownerCheckBox);
        holder.walkerCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.walkerCheckBox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    setClickListeners(convertView);   

    ParseObject pet = mPets.get(position);
    holder.petNameLabel.setText(pet.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_PET_NAME));
    return convertView;
}

private void setClickListeners(final View convertView)
{
   ViewHolder petHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   // If owner check is toggled, uncheck walker
   petHolder.ownerCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              //CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;//Wrong

              //Do a check here.
              if(petHolder==null)
              {
                 //or other thing that doesn't lead to a crash.
                 return;
              }       
              // Here's where the app crashes, 
              //here u can do better - like setting different than it was.//
              //not sure if I got what you were trying to do in the next lines.
              petHolder.walkerCheckBox.setChecked(!petHolder.walkerCheckBox.isChecked());
              //the next lines look weird.
              CheckBox wcb = petHolder.walkerCheckBox;
              wcb.setChecked(false);
              if (petHolder.walkerCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                   petHolder.walkerCheckBox.setChecked(false);
              }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Note the above code is not tested so copy-paste might not work. These are my observations based on your code. 
For a good understanding of the Holder pattern take a look here.
[Android ViewHolder Pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited out a line that might have been confusing. I accidentally left it in from debugging. The problem I'm having with this code is the same issue I was having before when trying to directly reference the checkboxes. When I reference `convertView` from within the onClick method I get an error saying `Variable convertView is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final`

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, it's my first app. This solution worked with only a minor addition: in the `setClickListeners()` method I needed to add `ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag()` before doing anything else. Also, I completely removed the lines that looked weird and changed `petHolder.walkerCheckBox.setChecked(!petHolder.walkerCheckBox.isChecked())` to `petHolder.walkerCheckBox.setChecked(!petHolder.ownerCheckBox.isChecked())`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Like I said didn't check every small detail. In general the system works very simple. You start by having a list of data that shows up in the first 6-7 views. Once you initialized this views, if you for example decide to see more, when you scroll down, all you do is to reuse the views. In the view holder you just store data you need to reuse for each view.